# Django 1.11 - It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format."]

Tags: python, powershell, python-3.4, postgresql-9.6, django-1.11

I know there was such a question, but it did not work for me well.
I get a message from the console when I do "migrate".
How to deal with this error?
I would like someone to tell me tpo step by step.
I would be very grateful.
I am using for virtualenv python 3.4, postgresql 9.6 and powershell.[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you run makemigration afterwards, can you show us relevant last migration. Also try to copy paste your code instead sending snips.

Comment: First I run "makemigrations and then "migrate". Do You want code, my last migrations? Or alls my migrations from folder "migrations"  snips?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sqlmigrate` instead

`python manage.py sqlmigrate <app_label> <migration_name>`

(migration name doesn't require the `.py` suffix.

And then enter your dbshell

`python manage.py dbshell`

and then copy and paste the code from the sqlmigrate into the terminal.

Comment: This not working, all the time I get the same message.

Comment: Yes, I have added

Comment: Hm I do not understand until the end. Do you mean data in django admin panel, for "added" field?

Comment: Yes, if I could see what the data in the "added" field currently looks like it might help to fix the problem

Comment: Aaa ok. Now I undrestand. When I trying data I receives message in the browser: ERROR: column "added" relationship "page_summary" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "page_summary" ("title", "added") VALUES ('Save ..